# Add Contents of Pointers to BSTR

Tags: c++

I have two Pointers to BSTRs:

```
BSTR *r1;
BSTR *r2;
```

now i want to return "r1 + r2" but this isn't possible like this because these aren't strings but pointers. 
How do i combine them to one string the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [VarBstrCat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
BSTR r1_plus_r2;
VarBstrCat(*r1, *r2, &r1_plus_r2);
```